# CSS selecting only numbers for style

Tags: css, css-selectors

On my website, I have a part that reads "Weekdays 10:00 ~ 18:00 /*linebreak/
Saturdays 10:00 ~ 13:30"

And I am trying to get only the numbers to be formatted as "Courier New" font, specifically the "10:00 ~ 18:00" and "10:00 ~ 13:30" parts. And I want set all the rest (the alphabet texts) as "Open Sans" font. How would I get it styled the way I am envisioning using CSS? thank you.

Comment: How do you generate those date? Can you split it to set the hours into a `span`. With a class?

Answer (score -1):

```
Weekdays <span id="time">10:00 ~ 18:00</span>
Saturdays <span id="time">10:00 ~ 13:30</span>
```

.css

#time {
font-family : "Courier New"
}

Comment: `#id` is reserved for unique elements on the page. If several shares the same styling, they should share the same `.class`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set "Open Sans" font for the whole website, set it for the body tag

```
body { font-family: "Open Sans" }
```

Then you override it for any specific element, in your case
html:

```
Weekdays <span class="days-time">10:00 ~ 18:00</span>
```

css:

```
.days-time { font-family: "Courier New" }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback! I tried it like this: <html>
<head>
<style>
body 
.time { font-family: "Courier New" }   
body {margin-bottom: 16px;
font-family: Open Sans;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.6;
color: #333333;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Weekdays <span class="time">10:00~18:00</span></p>
<p>Saturdays <span class="time">10:00~13:30</span></p>
<p>(Sundays are our off-days.)</p>

</body>
</html>

but my problem now is that I cannot seem to get the styling for the non-time material to work. I'm not sure what the issue is as is..

Comment: Make sure to add the fonts using `@font-face`